# Скрыть или показать блок на основе url

Tags: javascript

Есть вот такой код, найденный на просторах интернета.

Есть шаблон payment.php и на основе него создаются страницы checkout и checkout/order-pay.

Нужно чтобы на одной странице скрылся блок а и показался блок б, а на второй наоборот.

Срабатывает на checkout, а на checkout/order-pay нет.

Заранее спасибо.

```
$(function(){
    var p = location.pathname;
    if(p.indexOf('order-pay') != -1)
     { 
        $('li.payment_method_cheque').hide();
        $('div#wcpgsk-dialog-validation-errors').hide();
    }  
});

$(function(){
    var url = window.location.href; 

    if (url.indexOf('checkout') > -1) { 
        $('li.payment_method_kassa').hide();
        $('div#wcpgsk-dialog-validation-errors').hide();
    }  
});
```

Comment: это все потому, что _checkout/order-pay_ - подходит под условие _url.indexOf('checkout') > -1_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот и решение.

```
$(function(){
    var p = location.pathname;
    if(p.indexOf('checkout/order-pay') > -1) {
        jQuery('li.payment_method_cheque').hide();
        jQuery('div#wcpgsk-dialog-validation-errors').hide();
        jQuery('.payment_method_cheque').hide();
    }
});

$(function(){
    var url = window.location.href;

    if (url.indexOf('checkout') > -1) {
        jQuery('li.payment_method_kassa').hide();
        jQuery('div#wcpgsk-dialog-validation-errors').hide();

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Если адрес страницы заканчивается именно как checkout или checkout/order-pay, то этот вариант сработает. Если нет, нужно поправить регулярные выражения

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var pathname = window.location.pathname;

    if (/(.*)checkout$/.test(pathname)) {

        //открываем скрываем блоки на странице с адресом "checkout"

        $('li.payment_method_cheque').hide();
        $('div#wcpgsk-dialog-validation-errors').hide();

    } else if (/(.*)checkout\/order-pay\/\d+\?(.*)/.test(pathname)) {

        //открываем скрываем блоки на странице с адресом "checkout/order-pay"

        $('li.payment_method_cheque').hide();
        $('div#wcpgsk-dialog-validation-errors').hide();

    }

});
```

Comment: где checkout/order-pay дальше идую произвольные данные ввиде ключа номера заказа и тд пример ниже. https://***.ru/checkout/order-pay/102173?pay_for_order=true&key=wc_order_57b4b4f76b147

Comment: поправил регулярку

Answer (score 0):

Так как условие *url.indexOf('checkout') > -1* будет выполняться для обеих страниц, следует объединить два условия и добавить дополнительную проверку, например так:

```js
$(function() {
  var p = "/checkout/order-pay/102173/?pay_for_order=true&key=wc_order_57b4b4f76b147",
    isOrderPay = p.indexOf('order-pay') != -1,
    isCheckout = p.indexOf('checkout') != -1;


  $('li.payment_method_cheque').toggle(!isOrderPay); // скрыть если на OrderPay
  $('li.payment_method_kassa').toggle(!isCheckout || isOrderPay); // скрыть если на Checkout и не на OrderPay

  $('div#wcpgsk-dialog-validation-errors').toggle(!isCheckout && !isOrderPay); // скрыть если на Checkout или на OrderPay
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="payment_method_cheque">cheque</li>
  <li class="payment_method_kassa">kassa</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @AlekseyAverin, и где на этой странице искать код?

Comment: @AlekseyAverin, обновил ответ - все работает - остается только `kassa`